# Rename the post title with media name - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, file, media, custom-post-type

I have a wordpress website with customs posts and metas boxes.
One of these manage some pictures and I want to force the title of the post.
It should be the same as the name of the media uploaded.

Is it possible ? And how ?

Thank's

Comment: Is the media attached to the post?  If so then it's possible to get the name of the file and set the title.  Using the function get_attached_media() you can get the media details.

Comment: Yes i can get the name of the file with my meta boxe datas. But how rename the post title when the file is loaded. 

I think it's possible in Javascript no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help.

I have used a filter but this one :

```
function modify_post_title($data){
      if($data['post_type'] == 'fcfm_photos' && isset($_POST['image'])) { 
         $data['post_title'] = substr($_POST['image'], -(strpos(strrev($_POST['image']),'/')));  
      }
      return $data;
    }
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'modify_post_title' , '99', 1 );
```

And when I save the post, the post title change automatically. This is what i want.

Comment: I put the post in "resolved" tomorrow. I can't do it now.

Comment: That's great! For the future, please specify more information in your question so people can address your requirements better.

Answer (score 1):

Manipulate the post title with a filter.

```
function change_post_title( $title, $id = null ) {

    if ( is_single() ) {
        $title = 'new title';
    }

    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'the_title', 'change_post_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: No worries glad I could help!